# Efficiently store questions exam-wise and also year-wise in Database tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am basically trying to solve this problem: "Efficiently find the exam and year in which a question was asked."

For the same year, a question can occur in multiple exams.

For the same exam, a question can occur in multiple years.

An exam occurs each year and only once a year.

An exam can contain multiple questions.

A question may not belong to any exam (for example, it is a self-made question) and in that case it will not belong to any year as well.

There are around **20** entries in **Exams table**.

Number of entries in **Year table** till date is around **30** and will **increase by 1** for each consecutive year on-wards.

**Number of Questions** in each exam each year is around **200**.

The solution that I can think of so far is following:

**Question table:**

```
QuestionId
.
.
around 10-15 more columns
.
.
```

**Exam table:**

```
ExamId
ExamName (like ExamA, ExamB, ExamC)
```

**Year table:**

```
YearId
YearValue (like 1942, 1947, 2013, 2018)
```

**YearwiseExamQuestion table:**

```
YearwiseExamQuestionId
YearId
ExamId
QuestionId
```

Please suggest if this a good design for a large set of questions?

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are designing your database around particular queries you want to derive from your data rather than by the characteristics of the data you are storing. This is problematic if you're trying to save data storage space. If you're not trying to save data storage space, you could go for this.

Your solution will still work, however, it just will take up more space than a more normalized solution. You could save space by making `Year Table` not a table, but a column in your `Exam Table` and getting the data by year with a query. If you did that, I think it's still feasible to make `Exam Table` and `Question Table` their own tables with foreign key `QuestionId` in the `Exam Table`.

Comment: I think QuestionId should not be used as foreign key in Exam table, as it will not allow to store multiple questions for the same Exam (ExamId is primary key)

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. You would need to make ExamId and QuestionId a concatenated primary key with QuestionId also being a foreign key.

Comment: But, I think it will not handle the scenario of a question repeating for a particular exam in multiple years. "A question can belong to multiple exams." plus it can repeat for multiple years for a given exam. I think, I should edit the question a little bit for more clarity. Thanks for your response so far.

Comment: Sounds good! I wish I could help better. If you're worried about the year as well you could make it a concatinated primary key with Exam Id, Question Id and a Year Id. I don't think the year should need an Id, like, you could use the whole date time stamp and then parse the year to avoid this, but I don't know exactly the problem you're trying to solve, so I'm not sure what would work best.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks fine, as in some table you have to maintain the questions corresponding to the exam, `YearwiseExamQuestion` seems the right table to hold it. Make the YearId,ExamId,QuestionId combination as composite primary key, so that your requirements are satisfied as told in the question. Also, make YearId, ExamId, QuestionId as Primary keys in the respective parent tables. `YearWiseExamQuestion` is the child table, which holds which question came for which exam on which year.

> For the same year, a question can occur in multiple exams.
>
> For the same exam, a question can occur in multiple years.